# A few of users' devices receive 403 response even though the request never make to the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, http

I have encountered a weird problem.
My APIs are hosting on AWS, all most all the APIs are working fine except one API.

The different between that API (let's call it license API) and the rest is that it accepts POST request with binary body.
About 99% of request sending to this license API is successful. And only about 1% of request is failure with 403 response.
But, the problem is my server logs, AWS logs doesn't have any record of those failed requests. Which means, those requests have never reached my system. Yet user's client app still receive 403 response.

Here is how the request structure look like

Method: POST

Headers:

- "UserData": a 3000 characters length of Base64 string
- "Content-Type": "text/plain"

Body:

- A binary data

I known for binary data body we should have use "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream". But since it works fine in our test environment I haven't changed it yet.

So I wonder if there is any possible network setup on user's side that could block those requests, such as VPN, Firewall, DNS...?

For example, a user's VPN detects that the request has Content-Type: "text/plain" with binary data body and decide to block that request.

Please notes that all the other APIs are working fine for all users, just the license API have this issue.

Many thanks for your time and support.

Comment: Is there any firewall or some type of WAF?

Comment: Hi @MiladAbooali, yes there is WAF setup. It is managed by different team and they said there is no record of those requests either.
If it is blocked because of WAF it should affect all users right, not just 1% of users is blocked.